# Laravel with two different lifetime sessions

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I'm trying to implement 'remember me' login using laravel framework. When user checks 'remember me' box, laravel keeps session data for a month. If user unchecked it, I want to keep session until user closes the browser.

I know how to control session when 'remember me' is checked. I configured sessions in config/session.php like below:

```
'lifetime' => 43200,
'expire_on_close' => false,
```

And I'm using sessions with global session helper

```
session(['accessToken' => SOME_ACCESS_TOKEN]);
Session::flush();
```

and so on.

But I don't know how to work when user logging in with 'remember me' unchecked. I tried to find a way to control the configuration

```
'expire_on_close' => true,
```

on the fly, based on user input, but failed. Please tell me how I could keep two different session lifetime configuration within one laravel framework. Or if I'm trying 'remember me' feature in wrong way, please guide me.

Basically, like I stated above, I'd like to keep session in a month with 'remember me', and keep session only until browser closing without 'remember me'.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get **remember me** functionality you shouldn't work with session configuration. Instead, you should use the functionality already built into Laravel.

When you authenticate user with **Auth::attempt()**, you can pass a boolean value as the second argument. Set it to true, if user checked **remember me** checkbox. Set it to false otherwise.

This way, when checkbox is checked, user will be remembered till they manually log out of application. Otherwise, they'll be remembered till they close the browser or session expires.

You can find some more informaton here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#remembering-users

Comment: Okay that's exactly what I wanted. But how should I direct Auth into different table than 'users'? In my case, I have table called USER (all capital letters). I looked into config/auth.php but it seems that's not what I'm looking for... Also, can I use Auth::viaRemember(), even if I set 'false' to Auth::attempt, as far as user doesn't close the browser? Thanks!!

Comment: I dug a little bit and found config/auth.php is actually what I needed. I changed 'providers' to point 'database' and 'USER' table. But now I get error saying 'ErrorException inGenericUser.php line 66 Undefined index: remember_token' although I made 'remember_token' column with VARCHAR(100) type. Do you know how I could fix this?

Comment: viaRemember tells you if user was authenticated with the remember-me cookie. If you authenticate the user manually with attempt, then viaRemember will get you false

Comment: I recommend you change the provider to "eloquent" and set "model" to your user class. This way Laravel will use your User model instead of operating on the table directly. Just make sure that you add "protected $table = 'USER';" to your User model.

Comment: You're getting "undefined index", which doesn't say that the column is missing. It's saying that you're trying to get the token from a table that doesn't contain it. Do you try to access the token manually anywhere in your code? COuld you post your controller code?

Comment: That was my bad. I have two different DBs - one is for production and one is for local test - and somehow I mixed up the column settings. Now it works great. One last question: I guess I could use Auth::check() to check if user has logged in, when "remember me" is unchecked and it'd be true until user closes the browser. Am I correct?