# Laravel with different session lifetimes

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Q: How to create sessions with different lifetimes in Laravel 5?

This question is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40258339/1474817). I do not want to use it for any kind of sign in or register. I simply want to store it for 5mins because the call to fetch this data sits on a different server and takes a while to fetch.

The problem is that I have another session that needs to be stored for longer and currently using the global config for this session:

```
/*
|---------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|---------------------------------
*/

'lifetime' => 30,
'expire_on_close' => true,
```

How can I give them different lifetimes? Thanks!

Comment: If it's a slow to acquire resource that can be used by other users as well then you should cache it instead of storing it in the session. (Caching is actually a reasonable solution for this case in general). Using the session is subject to the user's session cookie. Once that's gone its gone.

Comment: Hi apokryfos, thanks for your reply! That sounds reasonable. But its something that actually needs to update every minute but my grace is 5mins to avoid delay calling the same thing under 5 mins but also need to show correct data. It has to update progress bar of tv shows. Please advise?

Comment: First read up on [Laravel caching](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/cache) it will give you an insight on what can be done. You can still use the user's `session()->getId()` as part of the cache key or as a cache tag if you want things to be on a per-user basis.

Comment: It doesn't need to be per-user basis. I read about caching, so can i can save with `cache(['key' => 'value'], $minutes);` and fetch with `$value = cache('key');`? That's it?

Comment: What I usually do is `$value = Cache::remember('key',$minutes, function () { /* get and return the value if it's not in the cache */ });` this is mentioned in the [*Retrieve & Store*](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/cache#retrieving-items-from-the-cache) section and it's a simple convenience. It will get the value from the cache if it's there otherwise it will call the function store the result in the cache and then return the value.

Comment: Legendary! If you can put the above in an answer then I will mark it as correct answer as it did work for me and possibly the next guy that comes here. :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular case you should use the cache instead. I generally do:

```
$value = Cache::remember('key', now()->addMinutes(5), function () { 
    /* get and return the value if it's not in the cache */ 
});
```

`remember` is a convenience method to either get the value from cache or run the callback, put the result in the cache and return the result (meaning the next call will just hit the cache).

More information can be found in the documentation under [Retrieve & Store](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/cache#retrieving-items-from-the-cache)

Comment: Thanks bud! Works great if it's not per-user basis, which in my case is perfect! :)