# Laravel 5.2 override session lifetime variable

Tags: php, session, laravel-5, config, session-variables

So basically i want to override `session.lifetime` variable of config at runtime only for some users.

So in session.php config file, i set `lifetime = 60`. But for some specific users i want it for `120 minutes`.

**I tried:**

In myController's Login function

1. Check if user is special user
2. set `config(['session.lifetime' => 120])`
3. Make user login with `Auth::attempt()`.

But still it reflects `60 minutes` lifetime for every users. So how can i achieve different `session.lifetime` for different users?

**I also tried:**[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45247239/laravel-customized-session-lifetime-at-user-level) which is not working.

**Edit:** I do not want to cache any data or do not want to store any custom data in my session for specific time. I want to define for how long a user can be ideal in my website before he kicks out to login page. So definatly not a duplicate of [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46091713/laravel-with-different-session-lifetimes)

Comment: `session.lifetime` is set globally

Comment: why do you need multiple `session.lifetime` ?

Comment: In my application i have different `user_type` which is attached to every user. So depending on `user_type` session time is different. That is the requirement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel with different session lifetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46091713/laravel-with-different-session-lifetimes)

Comment: @madalinivascu No it is not a duplicate of what you have suggested. Please read my edits.

Answer (score 0):

Well as per my research on this, I came to know that `Laravel` sets `last_active_time` of User and might be in `Authentication` middleware they put some logic to  checks like

```
If((last_active_time + config_session_time) > current_timestamp) {
   'Send user to login page.';
}
else {
   'Update last_active_time = current_timestamp';
   'Continue';
}
```

Instead of setting `last_active_time` if Laravel comes up with a logic that sets `session_expire_time` then we can set dynamic session time. Otherwise, it seems to impossible to set a dynamic session time without twisting the current logic of Laravel.

Any Laravel team-member/expert here can correct me if I am wrong.